# Why i cant use "" symbols of Microsoft word in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I am trying to create a vector for columns names of my data set. I opened the .csv file with note pad.

> /app/csrf/;/app/xss/;/http/https_redirect/;/http/vulnerability/apache_expect_xss/;/http/vulnerability/apacheusers/;/http/vulnerability/cgi/;/http/vulnerability/clientaccesspolicy/;/http/vulnerability/content_search/;/http/vulnerability/cookies/;/http/vulnerability/dictionary/;/http/vulnerability/dir_traversal/;/http/vulnerability/docker_registry/;/http/vulnerability/domino/;/http/vulnerability/drupal/;/http/vulnerability/embedded/;/http/vulnerability/headers/;/http/vulnerability/httpoptions/;/http/vulnerability/ms10_070/;/http/vulnerability/multiple_index/;/http/vulnerability/negotiate/;/http/vulnerability/origin_reflection/;/http/vulnerability/outdated/;/http/vulnerability/put_del_test/;/http/vulnerability/shellshock/;/http/vulnerability/siebel/;/http/vulnerability/site_files/;/http/vulnerability/strutshock/;/malware/google/;/rdp/enumeration/;/smtp/open_relay/domain/;/ssh/auth_methods/;/ssl/cert/;/ssl/ciphers/;/ssl/mixed/;/tcp/timestamp/

Copied all columns to word. After that i converted all ; symbols to " , " symbol group.

> “/app/csrf/” , “/app/xss/” , “/http/https_redirect/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/apache_expect_xss/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/apacheusers/” , “/http/vulnerability/cgi/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/clientaccesspolicy/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/content_search/” , “/http/vulnerability/cookies/”
>   , “/http/vulnerability/dictionary/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/dir_traversal/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/docker_registry/” , “/http/vulnerability/domino/”
>   , “/http/vulnerability/drupal/” , “/http/vulnerability/embedded/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/headers/” , “/http/vulnerability/httpoptions/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/ms10_070/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/multiple_index/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/negotiate/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/origin_reflection/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/outdated/” , “/http/vulnerability/put_del_test/”
>   , “/http/vulnerability/shellshock/” , “/http/vulnerability/siebel/” ,
>   “/http/vulnerability/site_files/” , “/http/vulnerability/strutshock/”
>   , “/malware/google/” , “/rdp/enumeration/” ,
>   “/smtp/open_relay/domain/” , “/ssh/auth_methods/” , “/ssl/cert/” ,
>   “/ssl/ciphers/” , “/ssl/mixed/” , “/tcp/timestamp/”

Last one i copied this columns to R

```
namelist <- c(“/app/csrf/” , “/app/xss/” , “/http/https_redirect/” , “/http/vulnerability/apache_expect_xss/” , “/http/vulnerability/apacheusers/” , “/http/vulnerability/cgi/” , “/http/vulnerability/clientaccesspolicy/” , “/http/vulnerability/content_search/” , “/http/vulnerability/cookies/” , “/http/vulnerability/dictionary/” , “/http/vulnerability/dir_traversal/” , “/http/vulnerability/docker_registry/” , “/http/vulnerability/domino/” , “/http/vulnerability/drupal/” , “/http/vulnerability/embedded/” , “/http/vulnerability/headers/” , “/http/vulnerability/httpoptions/” , “/http/vulnerability/ms10_070/” , “/http/vulnerability/multiple_index/” , “/http/vulnerability/negotiate/” , “/http/vulnerability/origin_reflection/” , “/http/vulnerability/outdated/” , “/http/vulnerability/put_del_test/” , “/http/vulnerability/shellshock/” , “/http/vulnerability/siebel/” , “/http/vulnerability/site_files/” , “/http/vulnerability/strutshock/” , “/malware/google/” , “/rdp/enumeration/” , “/smtp/open_relay/domain/” , “/ssh/auth_methods/” , “/ssl/cert/” , “/ssl/ciphers/” , “/ssl/mixed/” , “/tcp/timestamp/”)
```

but R dont understand this symbols and giving me unexpected token error. Why?

Comment: Wow! So many steps in your process. Can you skip the Notepad and Word steps and just import the CSV file containing your column headers into R? Even easier, read the other file containing only the data and use the `scan` function to scan in your header file as the `col.names` argument with the appropriate separators matching those in the data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Word is using curly quotes instead of normal double quotes. R doesn't understand these. Try copying and pasting the following line into the R console (but don't run it)

```
writeClipboard(gsub("”|“", "\"", readClipboard()))
```

Now go to Word, select and copy the text, go back to R and hit return. The correct string is now on your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily skip all those steps. Your data file is presumably a CSV file with no column headers. The column headers are in another file, separated by semi-colons.

The CSV data file can be imported into R using `read.csv` with the `col.names` argument specified using the `scan` function to read the file containing the column headers:

```
read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE, col.names=scan("header.txt", what="character", sep=";"))
```